# Question about optimization formulation for finding all eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonal-matrices, qcqp

I am looking at the following optimization formulation for finding all the eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \Bbb R^{n\times n}$.

$$\min_{\mathbf{\Phi} \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}}\;\operatorname{tr} \left(\mathbf{\Phi}^\top\mathbf{A}\mathbf{\Phi}\right) \quad \text{s.t.} \quad \mathbf{\Phi}^\top\mathbf{\Phi} = \mathbf{I}$$

It appears, for example, in section 3.2 of this [tutorial](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.11240) on eigenvalue and generalized eigenvalue problems.

Since $\mathbf{\Phi}$ is a square orthogonal matrix, we have $\mathbf{\Phi}^\top\mathbf{\Phi}=\mathbf{\Phi}\mathbf{\Phi}^\top=\mathbf{I}$. Therefore, the objective value is independent of $\mathbf{\Phi}$:

$$\operatorname{tr}\left(\mathbf{\Phi}^\top\mathbf{A}\mathbf{\Phi}\right) = \operatorname{tr}\left(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{\Phi}\mathbf{\Phi}^\top\right) = \operatorname{tr}\left(\mathbf{A}\right)$$

So how come the solution of this problem is the matrix of eigenvectors? It seems that whatever orthonormal matrix I may use should yield the same minimum value. Moreover, if any orthonormal matrix is a minimizer, it should also satisfy the KKT conditions which result in (according to the link above),

$$\mathbf{A}\mathbf{\Phi}=\mathbf{\Phi}\mathbf{\Lambda}$$

But this is only true for the matrix of eigenvectors, so there seems to be some contradiction here.
I understand the problem only exists due to $\mathbf{\Phi}$ being square matrix. Can someone help me resolve it?

Comment: I think you point to the right reason in your penultimate sentence. You have this "trivial" result because $\Phi$ is square. If $\Phi$ with orthonormal columns isn't square, you don't have anymore $\Phi \Phi^T = \Phi^T \Phi$ of course for dimensional reasons.

Comment: @JeanMarie surely that's the reason ($\mathbf{\Phi}$ not being square), but I was looking for some deeper reason. For example, given that the constraint is satisfied (i.e., $\mathbf{\Lambda}$ is the Lagrange multipliers matrix), the derivative of the Lagrangian w.r.t $\mathbf{\Phi}$ is actually zero because it's independant of $\mathbf{\Phi}$. So this optimization formulation does not, in fact, give you the full eigenspace of $\mathbf{A}$. In that case, what *is* an optimization problem whose solution is the set of all eigenvectors of $\mathbf{A}$?

Comment: Pick any $a>\rho(A)$ (such as $\|A\|_\infty+1$). Let $B=\pmatrix{A&0\\ 0&a}$. Solve $\min_{\Phi\in\mathbb R^{(n+1)\times n}}\operatorname{tr}(\Phi^TB\Phi)$ subject to $\Phi^T\Phi=I_n$. Remove the last row of $\Phi$. Now you get the eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: "But this is only true for the matrix of eigenvectors" — why?

Comment: @user1551 Thanks, great answer!

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo because this is the definition of eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $\mathbf{A}$.

Comment: @AmitBoyarski But why is the Lagrange multiplier matrix $\bf \Lambda$ diagonal?  The result merely claims that $\bf \Lambda$ and $\bf A$ are similar, right?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes you are right. The tutorial I linked also has a proof that it has to be diagonal. In short,  it shows that it must be symmetric, hence diagonalizable by an orthogonal matrix, and then does a change of variables to make it diagonal, absorbing the orthogonal matrix into $\mathbf{\Phi}$.

Comment: The objective is not independent of $\bf \Phi$.  It is independent of $\bf \Phi$ when $\bf \Phi$ is orthogonal. I.e., it is independent over the feasible region.